# C++ smart_ptr doesn't cause stack overflow?

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, overflow, unique-ptr

I am a SWE learning C++, and building a simple LinkedList class using std::unique_ptr as references to `head` and `next`. This is the basic structure:

```
template <class T>
struct LinkedListNode {
    T value;
    std::unique_ptr<LinkedListNode<T>> next;

    // For debugging.
    ~LinkedListNode() {
        std::cout << "destructed for value " << this->value << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct LinkedList {
    std::unique_ptr<LinkedListNode<T>> head;
};
```

Using smart pointers, I expect that when a LinkedList instance gets deleted or goes out of scope, then `head` will be deleted, and each `next` node will be deleted recursively too.

And this is exactly what happens. However, when working with really long lists (~20M nodes), it surprisingly still works OK. Shouldn't it crash because of a stack overflow?

In order to very roughly estimate the size of my OS's stack, I wrote the following script:

```
int main() {
    struct s {
        static void p(int i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        p(i+1);
    };
    s::p(0);
}
```

And it crashed at iteration number ~175K, much less than the 20M nodes that I was able to deallocate before. What is going on? Am I missing something about the way unique_ptr works?

Comment: This doesn't look like a smart usage of `std::unique_ptr`. Holding a `unique_ptr` means owning ownership on an object. In a linked list a node doesn't hold ownership on the next node, it holds ownership on the data contained in itself.

Comment: Could you post the whole code you're discussing so that others could compile and see what happens?

Comment: Definitely! https://gist.github.com/manuelmenzella/0fd85280d5051abec2c7
Don't be too harsh ;)

Comment: @Jack, I was under the impression that I should always use smart pointers instead of raw pointers unless absolutely necessary. What structure do you recommend instead?

Comment: What kind of optimization did you use?  With optimization, recursion as the last step of a function should be converted to iteration and not cause stack overflow.  It looks like the recursion you indicated could be optimized that way (but I'm not certain).

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have indeed recursion, the real reason behind it not reaching stack overflow could be because it's a [tail-call recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) which could be optimized to an iterative solution.

With this snippet of code:

```
struct Node
{
  int value;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> next;

  Node(int value, Node* next) : value(value), next(next) { }

  ~Node()
  {
    if (value == 0)
      cout << "foo" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Node* node = new Node(0, nullptr);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    node = new Node(i, node);

  delete node;

  return 0;
}
```

By placing a breakpoint on the `cout` statement and inspecting the stack trace you clearly see that behavior is recursive:

[image]

The behavior is shown also [here](http://ideone.com/idIpVD) by using a base destructor to track when `~Node()` returns.

Since the `next` node must be destroyed before returning from the destructor, which leads to invoking `~Node()` again. This behaviour would be the same by using raw pointers and deleting next pointer directly in the destructor, which indeed has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965313/is-a-recursive-destructor-for-linked-list-tree-etc-bad).